# Pearson correlation for timeseries data

Tags: time-series, correlation, pearson-r

I have a dataset like below and want to calculate Pearson Correlation Coefficient as described in   https://peerj.com/articles/cs-1108/#table-4 . If I understand correctly, x can be numerical(temperature) or binary and y is a timeseries measured at different time intervals. Could you please someone explain me how to calculate Pearson Correlation for this type of data.

| Day | Holiday or not | mean temperature | Load at time 1 | Load at time 2 | Load at time 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 0 | 67 | 45.34 | 69.45 | 100.3 |
| 101 | 1 | 78 | 34.65 | 45.67 | 78.45 |
| 102 | 0 | 67 | 33 | 49.66 | 67 |
| 103 | 1 | 65 | 45 | 56.64 | 77.78 |
| 101 | 1 | 70 | 38 | 48.34 | 88.21 |

This is the actual data that they used in the paper:
[image]

Comment: So, which of these variables is $y$?

Comment: Load time is y which is a time series

Comment: All the variables are time series! Do temperature and rainfall not vary in time? Why the odd data layout?

Comment: changed the variables to make more sense. I just made up some variables and these are the actual variables used in the paper. for independent variables:  min temperature, maximum temperature, weekend or not (0 or 1) holiday or not(00 or 1) etc and dependent variables : power load at every 15 minutes intervals

Comment: Sorry, but your new example makes no more sense to me than the old. If somehow temperature is a constant for a particular day but load is a time series, no correlation is defined between those two. The scatter plot is just a stripe and the correlation can't get beyond division by zero.

Comment: I agree with you. I have hard time understanding what they have done in the paper too, That's why I opened this question to get an insight.

Comment: The table looks like a compact form of presenting a *single* time series of quarter-hour measurements.  The "Pearson correlations" referred to in the paper appear to be correlations between these data and corresponding "influencing factors," as summarized in the paragraph following its Table 4.  That paragraph is wrong in many respects: it basically is using these *univariate* correlation coefficients to decide which variables to include in a multiple regression time series model. IMHO, any conclusions the authors made after this point should be ignored.